# How to clear element from all children in Angular (5+) Renderer2?

Tags: angular, angular5

Angular Renderer2 is recommended to manipulate DOM programatically.

In my directive i take some `el.nativeElement.innerText`, transform this text and want to add it to my element:

`` const text = renderer.createText(`${el.innerText}%`);
renderer.appendChild(el, text); ``

The problem is with `el` - it already has the text, so it appends transformed text after it.

I checked Renderer2 docs and it seems I can use `removeChild()` without passing reference to child, so I can't use Renderer2 to clear component first?

In this case only way to achieve it is using `innerText = ''` before renderer methods, which makes it pointless.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe something like:

```
const childElements = this.el.nativeElement.children;
for (let child of childElements) {
  this.renderer.removeChild(this.el.nativeElement, child);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is the right code:

```
    const childElements = this.el.nativeElement.childNodes;
    for (let child of childElements) {
      this.renderer.removeChild(this.el.nativeElement, child);
    }
```

Comment: This is correct, .children is problematic due to the limitations of supportive methods on HTMLCollection (this.el.nativeElement.children) vs NodeListOf<ChildNode> (this.el.nativeElement.childNodes), most prominently the forEach method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using the while loop. As long as there exists a child in the first position, the children will be removed from the end of the collection.

```
const myEl = this.el.nativeElement;

while(myEl.firstChild) {
  this.renderer.removeChild(myEl, myEl.lastChild);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:

```js
element.nativeElement.childNodes.forEach(node => {
  this.renderer.removeChild(element.nativeElement, node)
})
```